# How can we change ownership of a Heroku add-on

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to change ownership of a Heroku add-on? If so, how can we do that? In fact, I want to move an add-on from one Heroku account to another.

Let me elaborate my scenario a bit more to be clear.

I created an add-on with my test provider acount. Is there any way that I can delete the add-on from my test account and create the add-on with the same name with my official provider account? As a matter of fact, there is nothing about deleting the add-on or moving it under a different account in the Provider's documentation.

Comment: I would just email Heroku and ask them. They're very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're talking about ownership of [add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com) as an [add-on provider](https://addons.heroku.com/provider) and not just ownership of your heroku app, I would say you should probably contact the heroku add-on support team via email. [See this page here for an email address.](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources) Hopefully as an add-on provider if you submit a help ticket they'll be able to help you as well.

Comment: thanks for pointing to the resources page. I'll try to contact the Heroku team directly and see if they might be of some help in this scenario.

Comment: @ShahzadLatif Excellent! Keep me posted, or feel free to accept this answer if it works :)

Answer (score 4):

A Google search lead me to [this support page](https://getsatisfaction.com/heroku/topics/how_can_i_transfer_a_heroku_app_to_a_new_owner), which says

> This currently depends on whether or not the app has any paid resources associated with it.
>
> For an app with no paid resources, you can use "heroku sharing:transfer" from the command line to transfer the app to a new owner.
>
> For an app with paid resources, you have two options.
>
> 1) Remove all paid resources, transfer the app like a free app, then have the new owner re-add the paid resources.
>
> 2) Both the old and new owners should file a support tickets at http://support.heroku.com authorizing the transfer and with the new owner accepting charges for the app.

Also check out the [Transferring apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps) and [Collaborating with Others](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing) articles on Heroku's Dev Centre.

Comment: It looks like you're referring to the client apps while my question was about add-on. Probably, I need to edit my question to be more clear. But thanks for your response on this.

Comment: @ShahzadLatif Ahh, good clarification! Thanks. Yes for ownership of add-ons rather than client apps I would probably contact Heroku support. Changing add-on ownership sounds like a much less frequent situation

Comment: I sent an email to Heroku add-ons team, but didn't get any reply from them! :(